Angular Interceptor Implementation
so I am trying to implement an interceptor for my little app which is standalone: true, and all I want this interceptor to do is check that if the response from the server comes back with error 401 to log user so for that I wrote code with some console.logs to track it
auth.interceptor.ts
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private authService = inject(AuthService)
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Interceptor called', req);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout(); 
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}

my app.config.server.ts looks like that
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering()
  ]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptor/auth.interceptor';
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(), 
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true}
  ]
};

main.server.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

export default bootstrap;

main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));

but problem is that I can't even see this console.logs which I have in interceptor like interception is not even being called
I tried code above but its not working. (standalone: true)

your providers is not properly configured, see Implementation of interceptors in angular 17

Try this:
auth.interceptor.ts:
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
...
}

main.ts
import { authInterceptor } from...

providers: [...
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authInterceptor]))
...
]

